# How to debug web service application in eclipse?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, html, jakarta-ee

I am learning Java EE technologies. Is there a way I can use Eclipse debugger to step through the code and see how it works step by step? For instance, this is a simple html5 + restful service.

Is there any way I can debug from the index.html java script, and step through the code little by little in Eclipse? That would be the best way to study this stuff.

Thanks a lot.

```
/**
 * A simple CDI service which is able to say hello to someone
 * 
 * @author Pete Muir
 * 
 */
public class HelloService {

String createHelloMessage(String name) {
    return "Hello " + name + "!";
}
}

@Path("/")
public class HelloWorld {
@Inject
HelloService helloService;

@POST
@Path("/json/{name}")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage(name) + "\"}";
}

/** A simple rest service saying hello */
@POST
@Path("/xml/{name}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getHelloWorldXML(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage(name) + "</result></xml>";
}
}
```

Then, the front end html 5 + java script.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 + REST Hello World</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( '#sayHello' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var result = $( '#result' ),
        name = $.trim( $( '#name' ).val() );

    result.removeClass( 'invalid' );

    if( !name || !name.length ) {
        result.addClass( 'invalid' ).text( 'A name is required!' );
        return;
    }
    //console.log("clicked: " + name);
    $.ajax( 'hello/json/' + name, {
        dataType:'json',
        data:{},
        type:'POST',
        success:function ( data ) {
            //console.log("success: " + data.result);
            $( '#result' ).text( data.result );
        }
    })
    .error( function() {
        //console.log("error");
    });
});
}); // (document).ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
HTML5 + REST Hello World<br>
<form name="theForm">
<fieldset>
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" required placeholder="Your Name"/>
    <input type="submit" id="sayHello" value="Say Hello"/><span id="result"></span>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You can try using breakpoints in eclipse

Comment: But can't set breaking point in javascript.

Comment: Only the Java code is running on your server. You can debug that inside Eclipse, when it's run on your application server. The HTML & Javascript are run on your browser, so you'll have to debug them with a browser add-on (Firebug for FireFox for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Usually for any html/css/javascript code, I debug using the Chrome Browser's built in Dev Tool.  You can also install plugins for Eclipse that will allow you to step through Javascript.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uzSw_fb7NQ

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/debug/

The Rhino Debugger has been around for many years.

As for stepping in through the Web Service, you can write test classes and/or set breakpoints in eclipse.

This tutorial will help.... http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/debug-your-axis2-web-service-3-steps-using-eclipse/